# Android: how to get AutoCompleteTextView inside onItemClick

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to get an AutoCompleteTextView's ID after I clicked a value on the list. Tried looking up on google and stackoverflow, but the provided answers didn't work. Here's what I've got:

Created the view in my class declaration:

```
public class ActivityCadastrarCliente extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    AutoCompleteTextView E_Nome_Cliente, E_CPF;
    List<String> Nomes = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
```

Associated the view to an XML element:

```
E_Nome_Cliente = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Nome_Cliente);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Nomes.toArray(new String[0]));
E_Nome_Cliente.setAdapter(adapter);
E_Nome_Cliente.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and my onItemClick method is called normally as below:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //switch (parent.getId()) { 
        //case R.id.Nome_Cliente:
            ...

    //}
}
```

Does anybody know how I can access this view inside onItemClick? Tried several ways, but I only get exceptions:

```
//Class cast exception
AutoCompleteTextView input = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.getParent();
//Class cast exception
AutoCompleteTextView input = (AutoCompleteTextView)parent;
//Class cast exception
AutoCompleteTextView input = (AutoCompleteTextView)parent.getParent();
```

I need to identify which view was clicked, because I'm using 3 to 5 AutoCompleteTextView and based on the selected value I'll automatically fill in a bunch of other fields.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the class `AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392355/2306907).

Change your `setOnItemClickListener` call in the following way:

```
E_Nome_Cliente.setOnItemClickListener(
        new AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener(E_Nome_Cliente, this));
```

Now you can get the id by accessing the modified view parameter:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //view had been modified by AutoCompleteTextViewClickListener 
    //to contain the original AutoCompleteTextView
    switch (view.getId()) { 
        case R.id.Nome_Cliente:
            //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();

    if (adapter == autoCompleteTextView1.getAdapter()) {

        // Do something

    } else if (adapter == autoCompleteTextView2.getAdapter()) {

        // Do something else

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what do you mean by view id? do you want to get the selected value?
if yes, then the below code will do it, otherwise please clarify more what do you need and why you want to access the view itself.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //switch (parent.getId()) { 
       String selected = adapter.getItem(position);

    //}
}
```

more on adapter methods are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int))

Comment: View id = The int corresponding to the AutoCompleteTextView the user was filling. The same as R.id.id_of_autocompleteTextView. I need to access it because that correspond to a column inside my database I'll use to run a query in order to fill other views.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer i can't understand, what makes you need such thing? did you used android resource id (r.id.xxx) inside the database?

Comment: Yes I did. I store a JSON object with keys matching R.id.xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent.findViewById(R.id.id_of_autocompleteTextView)` on the parent of the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't help me identify which view was clicked. I can have 3 to 5 AutoCompleteTextViews. I'm trying to find the Id for which view the user was filling.

Comment: `onItemCLick` gives the position of the list item that was clicked.. Do you have more than one AutoCompleteTextView in a list item?

Comment: I have 3 Lists associated with 3 AutoCompleteTextViews.

Comment: then you'll have 3 `onItemClickedListener` for each of the AutoCompleteTextViews also right? So you can easily find out which onCLickListener was called

Comment: Hum, that will probably work! But I like to "center" all listeners in a single method. Code looks more organized to me. That's why I used "implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener" after my class that extends Activity. Any way I can achieve the same result if I decide to use "implements OnItemClickListener"?